# Prevent stata output window from dropping old analysis

Tags: stata

As i run more commands in Stata, the earlier output disappears from the window (i.e, if i scroll to the top, the earlier output is no longer there, suggesting that there is a set 'height' or number of rows of the output window).

Is it possible to change this setting, i.e., to increase the amount of output that is displayed?

Comment: To keep an arbitrary amount of output, rely on keeping a `log`, not finite buffer contents.

Comment: See `help scrollbufsize` for an explanation of the means of expanding the scroll buffer size, although I personally follow Nick's guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion in the comments - in case of relevance to anyone else, this can be achieved with the command:

```
  set scrollbufsize 2000000
```

(or any value up to 2000000) - this takes effect the next time Stata is opened.